# using AJAX post => js file is rendered but div is unchanged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, post, render

In my Ruby on Rails application I would want to change the table with id=table_div in my view but when I use ajax post and want to render add_result_options.js.erb file nothing happens. 
I have this script

```
$.ajax({
 type : "POST",
          url :  'http://localhost:3000/systems/add_result_options',
          dataType: 'json',
          data :  { results : { name : array_results } }
});
```

in my SystemsController:

```
def add_result_options

    @resultOptions = params[:results]   

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.js   { render :add_result_options }
    end
end
```

in my add_result_options.js.erb file

```
$("#table_div").remove();
```

My view named create.html.erb I have the table which I would like to change

```
<table id="table_div">
     <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Serial</th>
            .......
     </tr>
</table>
```

When ajax is called in the console I can see that the post ran but nothing in the table changes:

```
Processing by SystemsController#add_result_options as JSON
  Parameters: {"results"=>{"name"=>["name", "memory", ""]}}
  Rendered systems/add_result_options.js.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add html to the #table_div you have to use the deferred to insert data once the Ajax-call is complete:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  'http://localhost:3000/systems/add_result_options',
    dataType: 'json',
    data :  { results : { name : array_results } }
    success: function(data) {
        $("#table_div").append(data);
        //Alternativly
        //$("#table_div").html(data);
    }
});
```

If you want to render ruby code in javascript, you have to render the javascript like so:

**view.html.erb**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url :  'http://localhost:3000/systems/add_result_options',
    dataType: 'json',
    data :  { results : { name : array_results } }
    success: function(data) {
        $("#table_div").append(data);
        <% system = System.first %> 
        var system = <%= raw System %>; 
    }
});
</script>
<table id="table_div">
     <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Serial</th>
            .......
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok, but can I execute ruby code, for example queries from the database in this block?  success: function(data) {
        $("#table_div").append(data);
//for exampe      
 <% system = System.first %>
        var system = <%= raw System %>;
    }...

Comment: Ruby code is executed when rendering a template so if you include javascript in a template blocks can be rendered as part of javascript code, but if you are including this file to your template (create.html.erb) then no ruby code can be executed. **Note that even if you render ruby code as javascript code this will be executed before any javascript is executed**

Comment: That is the reason why I wanted to render the add_result_options.js.erb file so there ruby could would be executed. But nothing renders even if the console writes that it rendered the add_result_options.js.erb file. Because according to the data i send with the post I want to change the div then.